# get values of sql return php

Tags: php, post

I have this model

```
class LoginModel extends Database
{
    public function signIn($userName,$password){
        return $this->select("select count(*) as o_user_exists from users where usuario = ? and password =  ?");                    
    }
}
?>
```

My function ***select***

```
public function select($query = "" , $params = [])
{
    try {
        $stmt = $this->executeStatement( $query , $params );
        $result = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);             
        $stmt->close();

        return $result;
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        throw New Exception( $e->getMessage() );
    }
    return false;
}
```

and in my controller i have

```
$userModel = new LoginModel();            
 $actionSignIn = $userModel->signIn($p_userName,$p_password);        
 $responseData = json_encode($actionSignIn[0],true); 
 echo $responseData->o_user_exists;
```

[image]

how i can get values from this return?

```
{"o_user_exists":1}
```

i edit my  Code to

```
 $userModel = new LoginModel();            
                $actionSignIn = $userModel->signIn($p_userName,$p_password);                                        
                $responseData = json_decode(json_encode($actionSignIn),true);                 
                echo $responseData['o_user_exists'];
```

and now y get Undefined index
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting an JSON object as a result. You can `json_decode` and access it as an array.

```
$responseArray = json_decode($response, true);
$responseArray['o_user_exists'];
```